# Hilbert space isomorphism

Tags: hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $G$ be a countable group. I know that $H\otimes \ell^2(G)$ is isomorphic to $\ell^2(G,H)$. Can you please help to find an explicit isomorphism?

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain what is $\ell^2(G,H)$.  I'm guessing it is the space of functions $f: G \rightarrow H$ such that $$\sum\limits_{g \in G} ||f(g)||^2 < \infty.$$

Comment: Most likely you can define a map $H \otimes \ell^2(G) \rightarrow \ell^2(G,H)$ first on elementary tensors by sending $v \otimes f$ to the function $$g \mapsto f(g)v.$$ Then extend to the completion.

Comment: Thank you so much